# scaling function used by BitmapData.draw function?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, scaling

What scaling functions are used by the [BitmapData.draw](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw()) function for smooth and not smooth drawing?

(Libraries like [clevrlib](http://www.clevr.com/blog/2008/resize-actionscript-bicubic-bilinear-interpolation) allow for bilinear and bicubic sampling, which suggests that neither is what flash is doing natively.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Foundation ActionScript 3.0 Image Effects by Todd Yard (page 155)

"...the smooth parameter determines whether a scaled up image is smoothed upon scaling.  Basically, a value of false, which is the default, will perform a nearest-neighbor algorithm on a pixel, which can result in visible pixelation.  A value of true will result in a bilinear algorithm being applied, which calculates new pixel values based on the average value of multiple surrounding pixels."